# Trigger PHP function when Javascript time event activates

Tags: javascript, php, timer

Is it possible to trigger a php function every minute or so using Javascript without going to another page?

Comment: You can use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: Please learn the basics of Ajax first. You can use jQuery if you are beginner, it abstracts lot of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a loop in your PHP script and use the `sleep()` function.

The doc for `sleep()` [here](https://www.php.net/sleep)

Or you can do that

```
var milliSeconds = 6000;

setInterval( function() {

var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // code for IE6, IE5
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         console.log ( xmlhttp.responseText );
      } 
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","functions.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();


}, milliSeconds);
```

You have to load xmlhttp request object according to the browser ( xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); ), then set an event handler when the xmlhttp state changes ( xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() ). When it changes check if the status is 200 (success) then do whatever you want with the response. ( I printed it to console )